# How to change priority level on conditional formatting in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA in excel 2013 and I have a question regarding setting the priority. I am trying to *change the priority* of my conditional formatting in a range. The **last line** before the End If is where I am having the issue. As of right now it is only inserting into the #1 position rather inserting into the #2 position. I have tried following the documentation on Microsoft, such as this page ->

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.formatcondition.priority.aspx

As well as other helpful pages that show examples->

https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2005/10/14/conditional-formatting-using-vba-some-examples/

But neither of these ultimately ended up working.

```
Range("F6:F9").Select
If Selection.FormatConditions(2).Interior.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314 Then
Else    
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=MATCH($F$3,$H$6:$H$9,FALSE)"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    [...]

    ***Selection.FormatConditions(1).Priority = 2***
End If
```

Comment: What does it do instead of working?

Comment: Currently, with the way it is and the way QHarr suggested, it still inserts inserts as the first priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work-around! Instead of trying to insert the new formatting into the #2 position, first set the new formatting to the #1 position, *THEN* set the #2 position to the #1 which then bumps down the new formatting to the #2 position. Essentially, **move everything else** and it will take care of itself.

```
Range("F6:F9").Select
If Selection.FormatConditions(2).Interior.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314 Then
Else

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=MATCH($F$3,$H$6:$H$9,FALSE)"
    ***Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority***
    [...]
    ***Selection.FormatConditions(2).SetFirstPriority***
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested with the range conditionally formatted containing the values 1,2,3,4 and used the following:

```
Range("F6:F9").FormatConditions.Item(1).Priority = 2
```

Then the following returns 2:

```
Debug.Print Range("F6:F9").FormatConditions.Item(1).Priority
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried your solution but it is still inserting into the #1 position rather than the #2. I have multiple formattings that I am needing to insert into.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
```